# Update MySQL db with csv file

Tags: php, mysql

What is the proper syntax for a Query in Navicat to accomplish the following with a data upload from a cvs file to a MySQL db?

a) if record exists at destination and not in source file, delete the record.

b) if record does not exist at destination but exists in source file, add the record.

c) if record exists in both destination and source, update only columns 1 through 3 (leaving columns 4 and 5 untouched)

Thanks

Comment: What things you have tried?

Comment: Thanks, Kailash I'm running into two issues. First, I'm getting access Denied for User HvF when trying to invoke: load data infile '/mydata.csv' into table test fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' ignore 1 lines (id, mycol1, mycol2);  Secondly, I'm not sure whether it would handle the data the way I need it with a) b) and c)

Comment: Thanks, Kailash I'm running into two issues. First, I'm getting access Denied for User HvF when trying to invoke: load data infile '/mydata.csv' into table test fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' ignore 1 lines (id, mycol1, mycol2);  Secondly, I'm not sure whether it would handle the data the way I need it with a) b) and c)  note I don't have any access permission problems when using the Import Wizard in Navicat.

Comment: @HvF.. you can perform all above operation using php and mysql..